# Copying huge files into container (from arbitrary location)?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

Docker newbie doing a POC. We have one web service that relies on a huge 3rd party library (30GB+). I'm playing around with how to get it into the container so I can run the installer.

From my understanding, and like I said, I'm a newbie, the Dockerfile is going to produce layers? So if the first step is installing the 30GB library, that should be a cached layer, correct?

A few ugly catches:

```
1) the library needs to be updated once a month
2) we have a build / deployment group, so I'd like to set it up in a way where they can do it... they aren't developers, so this would ideally be as automated as possible for them. They do build the code and have a powershell script to deploy to all the VMs we currently use.
3) they use team build to build the visual studio solutions, but they just push the build button, they don't really do much beyond that.
```

So ideally, they'd download the monthly update zip, put it in a specific location then run the team build and the dockerfile would copy the zip into the container and run the monthly install.

Obviously I don't want to rebuild the entire image from scratch every build which is why I was mentioning that it would be the first step.

Or do I need to go the whole route of building a custom image?

Comment: And mounting as a volume isn't an option?

Comment: @user3483203 isn't the way it works is that you take the stock image, run the installer on it and then use that as the "base" for builds? would mounting / installing happen during the build process of the image?

Comment: @user3483203 can you provide an example of how to mount in the dockerfile for Windows? Say for example the file is in c:\test? I tried many syntaxes, none work.

Comment: why dont you just use a COPY command in your dockerfile?

Comment: @PekosoG I have been trying to figure out the syntax for like a day now... nothing is working... what is the syntax to copy c:\test\test.zip to the root for example? Seems like it should be really straight forward lol...

Comment: @PekosoG since the 3rd party library is 30GB, would it be better to mount vs copy?

Comment: if you choose volume, then you'll need to copy the whole folder in order to make it work somewhere else. But if you choose copy, you can upload the image to some host and just use it anywhere you want. But in both scenarios, the whole "environment" would be the same size i guess